# How to change the cursor using ExtJS

Tags: extjs, mouse-cursor

I would like to set a column of a grid to change cursor to pointer once hovered.

I dunno if its best practice to apply a style to it, you tell me please.

I just cant figure it out.

This is my code and I wish the column would change cursor upon mouse hover.

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.Panel', {
store: services,
xtype: 'log',
features: [groupingFeature],
stateId: 'stateGrid',
columns: [
    {
        text: 'URL',
        sortable: true,
        flex: true,
        dataIndex: 'url'
    }
  ]
});
```

thank you for help

Comment: This is very easy if you only have one column in the grid, like the code above shows. Do you plan on having more columns? Also, I am assuming you mean a mouse hover on the **data** part of the column, not the **header**, is that right?

Comment: I will have several columns... Yes I mean mouse hover on the data part, what do you mean header, where did you get that from? :)

Answer (score 10):

It works for me:

```
columns: [
{
    text: 'URL',
    sortable: true,
    flex: true,
    dataIndex: 'url',
    renderer: function (val, metadata, record) {
            metadata.style = 'cursor: pointer;'; 
        return val;
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

With most components, one can directly attach CSS snippets alike:

```
 Ext.define('...', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.CartesianChart',
    legend: {
        style: 'cursor: pointer;'
    }
});
```

When using a `renderer`, one can also attach a CSS class (and whatever styles):

```
renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
     meta.tdCls += 'x-cursor-pointer'; 
     return value;
}
```

`Ext.grid.column.Column` also has a `componentCls` property: [Ext.grid.column.Column#cfg-componentCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-componentCls) and a `style` property: [Ext.grid.column.Column#cfg-style](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-style)... which would set the style for the the whole column, instead of each indivivual row - or one can combine, by adding a class to the whole column and further classes with the renderer, according to the values (and then use these combined CSS selectors).